# Can't trim periods (...) and ellipsis (...) from strings in vb.net 

Tags: vb.net, string

I'm getting a very strange result when I try to use string.trim to remove characters.

I want to remove leading and trailing periods (...) from strings, but my code only removes trailing characters for some reason. Microsoft's documentation says that the string.trim(char array) method should trim from the start and end of the string. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zke31k1x.aspx

My code to trim the string is...
`mystring=mystring.trim(".")`

if the input is "2342...." it gets shortened to "2342" but if the input is "...2342" the output is still "...2342"

I've tried defining a character array with 1 member (i.e. "."), but I get the same result.

I've also tried mystring.trimstart(".") but it does not work either

I'm pretty confused about why I'm getting this behavior

**EDITED/SOLVED:**
mystring included two different characters that represent dots (.)

One of the characters in mystring was three dots as an ellipsis (the three together were encoded as a single character with a value of 133). The other was a simple period (value of 46).

This solves the problem:

```
mystring=mystring.Trim(Chr(133))   'removes ellipsis
mystring=mystring.Trim(Chr(46))    'removes periods
```

Comment: Also don't forget you can nest the `Trim` methods if you think is makes it more readable: `mystring=mystring.Trim(Chr(133)).Trim(Chr(46)) `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried it right now:

```
Dim mystring = "...2342"
mystring = mystring.Trim(".")
Console.WriteLine(mystring)
```

but result is always **2342**.
Are you sure that first char in "...2342" is a "."? Did you check its ASCII value?
Which framework are you using? I'm using Framework 4.0.

**EDITED:** try this to get ascii values

```
For Each c As Char In mystring.ToCharArray()
    Console.Write(Hex(Asc(c)) & "-")
Next
Console.WriteLine()
```

Comment: Yeah. Your result makes a lot of sense. But I am not getting that. I tried re-starting visual studio, but no luck. Maybe it has to do with the way my program is doing character encoding?

Comment: @akh2103: extract ASCII code of the first char and compare it with the one of "."; if it's different you've found the problem...

Comment: @Marco - Oh yes apologies I'll delete my comment since it doesn't make sense

Comment: @akh2103: I saw you solved your trouble. Remember you should [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you think it solved (or helped to solve) your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just tried this:

```
Dim mystring = "...2342"
mystring = mystring.Trim(".")
```

mystring is always 2342 no matter what permutation I try.

Have you definetly checked the result correctly?  You're not checking it in break mode before the operation has taken place?

I agree with @Marco, perhaps the "." you used was not the same as the input.

Comment: yeah. any pointers on how to find out if the two periods are the same character?